How to change the menu font size in IDLE?
While I'm using Python's IDLE, the font size of menus and submenus is very small.
In the editor window the font size is 14. On a large 4K monitor, working with files is fine but sometimes if I need to select something from the menu and it's hard to read the options, especially if I do it over remote desktop and the screen is scaled down for the window on my machine.
Please see the screenshot below:

Any idea how to increase it?
I tried to modify some of the statement with definition of font size in some configuration files in the corresponding idlelib directory but with no success. I would expect the menu sizes are configurable or at least change correspondingly if I modify the font size in the editor window.

What OS are you using?

Confirmed. Options, Configure IDLE does not change menu font size on Windows 10
Python 3.11 either. This should be an option as hi-res monitors become more popular. Has someone made a Github issue for this yet?

Currently, IDLE creates the editor/shell horizontal menubar with default options in idlelib.editor at line 120: self.menubar = Menu(root).  The tk Menu doc says that a font option can be passed.  However, I tried adding , {'font':Font(root, Font(family=Name,size=14)}, with Name being Courier/Monaco, on Windows/macOS, but to no effect.  This seems to be a tkinter, tk, or os issue.
The answer by a tkinter expert to this {tkinter question]2 says "You cannot change the font of the menubar or its menus with tkinter. Those menus are rendered by the underlying OS rather than being rendered by tkinter."  He has given the same answer to other questions.

Well, I got here no hint so I searched a little and found some "dirty" possibility.
I added 2 explicit font definition: "font=("DejaVu Sans", 12)" within the def of "createmenubar" located about line 500 within the file "editor.py" in directory "idlelib" (one has to find correct dir using "which idle" and "find / -name idlelib 2>/dev/null") - both lines with DejaVu in the picture
It worked for me - maybe somebody can show me how to do it correctly, please.
Anyway I can use IDLE now without a magnifying glass. See an attached screen shots

Interesting.  I believe I tried the tuple form of specifying a font also on the top menu creation call on 120.  You patched the call the creates each of the dropdown menus.  I did not think it would affect the already created top menu.  I will experiment more.  I would like my top menu a bit bigger also.

Go to Options > Configure IDLE, then a window/menu should pop up that lets you change the font and size. There are also other buttons you can click in the configuration screen that let you change the font color and more.

The OP is talking about the title bar menu File Edit Shell ... which are not affected by the IDLE settings (see my answer).
